# View [layouts.account] not found. Whats the issue? [AsgardCms]

Tags: php, laravel, asgardcms

I'm having an issue of `AsgardCms` which is made with Laravel. I created a Theme on Asgard and then it goes well. But after sometime if I logout from the backend and want to log in again or after my system reboot, It throws an error:

> View [layouts.account] not found. (View:
>   \Modules\User\Resources\views\public\login.blade.php)

If I setup new project again, It works again and then  after that same error throws.

I am newbie of Laravel aswell as Asguard. I searched the problem but really didn't find anything with my error.
PS: I cleared the artisan cache, view and publish theme also composer update. But really didn't help. What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Check for [layouts.account] layout with exact name **account** i think in your view the layout you called doesn't exist or misspelled you can share you code for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer, I did created a new theme, And **account.blade.php** is missing in the /themes/your-theme/views/layouts folder. 
So, from the default theme(Flatly), I copied the **account.blade.php** on /themes/your-theme/views/layouts folder and it fixed my issue. 
Thanks everyone!